# Close Lightbox on Custom Form Submit

Tags: 6, javascript

I am using form Api to create a custom form. My form is below.

```
function myform_form() {
  $form = array();
  $form['name'] = array(
    '#type'          => 'textfield',
    '#title'         => t(''),
    '#required'      => FALSE,
    '#weight'        => 2,
  );
   $form['telephone'] = array(
    '#type'          => 'textfield',
    '#title'         => t(''),
    '#weight' => 3,
    );
     $form['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('submit'),
     );
  return $form;
}

function myform_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_set_message(t('Your form has been submitted successfully.'));
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'thankyou';
}
```

I used to show this form in lightbox as this :

```
<a href="/myform" rel="lightframe"> Form </a>
```

Form is correctly showing in lighbox. But when i submit the form it opens the `thankyou` page in popup.

I used

`<a href="/myform" rel="lightmodal"> Form </a>`

It closes the popup event if form validation returns false. I don't want to close the popup if there is any validation error. I added this to `myform_submit` function :

```
parent.Lightbox.end();
```

But `drupal_add_js` is not working in `myform_submit` function.

Updated :

I send a parameter to thank you page and added this on the page load.

```
<?php if($_GET['redirect']) { ?>
  <script> 
      window.parent.location = "quick_request_quote";
  </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Its redirecting but it shows content in popup for few seconds and redirect after that. I don't want to display popup for a second also after submitting the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by creating a Menu showing processing message and redirect it using :

```
      window.parent.location = "thankyoupage";
```

Answer (score -2):

Hope this will help you,

For forms validation on modal dialog you can user [**Chaos tool suite**](https://drupal.org/project/ctools) module.

Steps

- Download and enable Chaos tools and Chaos Tools (CTools) AJAX Example
- Go to the URL **your_site/ctools_ajax_sample**
- You can refer ctools dialog form examples using sites/all/modules/contrib/ctools/ctools_ajax_sample

  - Where **contrib** is the folder where I keep all my contributed modules.

Comment: Could you please explain **how** to use ctools for that effect? It's a big and complicated set of tools, just pointing at it will be useless for at least some readers.

Comment: updated my question check.

Comment: Better now. I did not downvoted you so I cannot un-downvote, and it's still hardly anything but pointing at examples, so I'm not so sure if it deserves upvote. Let's leave it to downvoters and question's author.